# Currency Regex - Euro/Pound/Dollar

Tags: regex, currency

I need to create a regex which captures all different types of currency such as:

```
£1
$100,000,000
€25.00
25p       (pence)
25c       (cents)
25m       (million)
25bn      (billion)
25 million
25 billion
£0.25
```

Currently, I've got the following:

```
^(([^0]{1})([0-9])*|(0{1}))(\.\d{2})?$
```

This works for:

```
£100
200 -- don't want this to be included
$200
€400
350 -- don't want this to be included
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a pattern like this:

```
^([£€$]([0-9]([0-9,])*)(\.\d{2})?|([0-9]([0-9,]))(\.\d{2})?([pcm]|bn| [mb]illion))$
```

This will match either:

- A `£`, `€`, or `$` followed by a number which may contain commas, followed by an optional `.` followed by two more digits.
- A number which may contain commas, followed by an optional `.` followed by two more digits, followed by `p`, `c`, `m`, `bn`, or a space, followed by `million` or `billion`.

Here's a [demonstration](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5B%C2%A3%E2%82%AC%24%5D%28%5B0-9%5D%28%5B0-9%2C%5D%29%2a%29%28%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%3F%7C%28%5B0-9%5D%28%5B0-9%2C%5D%29%29%28%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%3F%28%5Bpcm%5D%7Cbn%7C%20%5Bmb%5Dillion%29%29%24&input=%C2%A31%0A%24100%2C000%2C000%0A%E2%82%AC25.00%0A25p%0A25c%0A25m%0A25bn%0A25%20million%0A25%20billion%0A%C2%A30.25%0A%0A%0A--%20will%20not%20match%20these%0A200%0A350)